# How to identify the Port Your Marketing Cloud Instance Utilizes

Tags: marketing-cloud, developer, new, ip

We're standing up a new MC account, and I was asked by a developer what the 'Port' on my MC instance is. I've briefly read up on Ports, but I'm still not sure what the number of ours is. Is there a way to find that information? The developer said it's "Most likely HTTPS using Port 443 or Port 8080". How can I confirm that Port #?